# Use two methods to find the General Solution of $e^{2y} + 2y\cos(x) + 2(xe^{2y}+\sin(x))y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would appreciate a hint here because I am completely stuck on this question. I'm not asking for an answer. Just what methodologies would work here. Exact DE? Ricatti? Poly-Sub? If I know what methodologies work. I think I could work the rest of the problem out.

Comment: Have you tried checking if it is exact?

Comment: @TotomaLover2312 isn't $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: @TotomaLover2312 isn't $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: $M\; dx + N\; dy = 0$ is the same thing as $M + N \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written as
$$
(e^{2y} + 2y\cos(x))dx + 2(xe^{2y} + \sin(x))dy = 0
$$
Now for the solution
$$
e^{2y} + 2y\cos(x) + 2xe^{2y}y' + 2\sin(x)y'= 0 \\
(xe^{2y})'+ 2y\cos(x) + 2\sin(x)y' = 0\\
(xe^{2y})'+ 2(y\sin(x))' = 0\\
xe^{2y}+ 2y\sin(x) = c\\
$$

Comment: Any idea how you'd form an equation of the form $y=f(x)$? I can't.

Comment: I can't either, it is transcendental equation in $y$, it can't be solve for $y$

Comment: Oh, so you solved it then :) Well done, very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Physor's solution
$$xe^{2y}+ 2y\sin(x) = c$$ the explicit solution is given in terms of Lambert function
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \left(c \csc (x)-W\left(x \csc (x)\, e^{c \csc (x)}\right)\right)$$